# How to reacquire object reference in Android after Activity recreation without serializing or parcealizing this object?

Tags: android, reference, persistence, android-lifecycle, dispose

I have an object which I know is persist, because it performs it's behavior. It is an extension of `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `SelectionTracker` inside, which I am connecting to my `RecyclerView` only once. After I rotate my screen, Activity recreates itself and all member fields turn to `null`, including field with extension of `RecyclerView.Adapter`. But it is still somewhere there, because `RecyclerView` still works and I can select and deselect items.

How can I reacquire a reference to this object?

I don't want to serialize or parcealize it, because it is in memory and working.

Also I wonder, under which circumstances Android will dispose objects in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in 2 ways:

- Tell Android that your app will handle the configuration change itself by adding `android:configChanges="..."` to your manifest. In this case, when the screen orientation changes, Android will not kill and recreate your `Activity`, it will simply call `onConfigurationChange()` on the existing instance and you can manage it yourself.
- Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. Upon an orientation change, Android will call `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` just before it kills the current `Activity`. In this case, implement the method and return `this` (the instance of the current `Activity`) from the method. Android will then kill the `Activity` and create a new instance. In `onCreate()`, you should call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. If this returns a non-null value, then this will be a reference to the `Activity` that got killed. You can now copy any data from member variables in the old instance to member variables in the new instance. In this way, you can take "migrate" anything necessary from the old instance of the `Activity` to the new instance.